# Failing to load json file into Google Colab

Tags: python, json, google-colaboratory

I am performing a machine learning implementation on a data given in json format.
I haven't tried much because I have no experience.

My code to read is:

```
with open('attempts.json') as my_file:
    d = json.load(my_file)
```

I am getting error like:

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

I have replaced my attempts.json file which was 260mb to grades.json which is 12kb but still having same problem.

[image]

Comment: try `d = json.load(my_file.read())`

Comment: now I am getting this error      AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: what is your complete code?

Comment: first I uploaded the json files using files.upload on colab,                                                       
then imported json, and then this code I mentioned in my question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your json file must have content and the format is correct.
Based on this error, I think your json file is empty.